# Issue with jQuery binding events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to front end programming. When I was learning jQuery I came across this issue. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var msg ="hi";
  $("#test1").click(function(){alert(msg)});
  msg ="hello";
  $("#test2").click(function(){alert(msg)});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  
<button id="test1">test1</button>
<button id="test2">test2</button>
```

On running this code, both the alerts prints "hello". I except the first button on clicking should alert with "hi". Why does it behave like this? Is this the right behavior? Is it because of scope constraint?

Comment: You overwrote the `msg` var..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of mostly correct explanations here but, much to my surprise, no one's thrown out the key concept here: closure.

Basically what's happening is when you declare your two functions, the scope they are declared in forms a *closure*.  That means that the variables inside that closure remain available to the functions.  In other words:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // this begins a closure
    var msg ="hi";
    // you are simply declaring a function here, not calling it
    $("#test1").click(function(){alert(msg)});
    msg ="hello";
    // ditto
    $("#test2").click(function(){alert(msg)});
    // the end of the closure...msg has the value "hello"
});
```

Then some time passes, and the click events get called.  The functions that are attached to the click events still have access to the closure (inside which the value of `msg` is "hello").

The traditional way to "capture" a variable's value inside a closure is to create an ["Immediately Invoked Function Expression" (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).  Basically you can think of this as creating an entirely new closure that contains the immediate value of a variable.  You could re-write your code to use IIFEs like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // this begins a closure
    var msg ="hi";
    // the following creates an anonymous function with a single parameter
    // AND invokes it immediately, creating another closure in which the
    // value of msg1 is "hi".
    (function(msg1){
        $("#test1").click(function(){alert(msg1)});
    })(msg);
    msg ="hello";
    // ditto
    (function(msg2){
        $("#test2").click(function(){alert(msg2)});
    })(msg);
});
```

I hope this makes it a little bit clearer what's happening, and how to get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You are having a **scoping** issue.

By the time you get to the point of the code that you actually *click* `msg === "hello"`

Comment: I wouldn't consider this an issue, seeing as it's the expected behavior. He is asking to alert the `msg` var from the DOM ready handler scope, it'll alert its current value.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté haha I never said it was an issue :-)

Comment: Not sure if Neal is in troll mood today. But +1 for the clear explanation `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté oooo cuz i used the word **`issue`**. ahhh, well what other word could I use?

Comment: Iunno, just shooting random comments as usual. Guess it can be considered an `issue` for the OP yes. `:P`

Answer (score 2):

The value of `msg` is "hello" when the handler code is being executed.

Alternatively you can pass it as data to the handler function access it..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var msg ="hi";
  $("#test1").click({msg: msg}, function(e){alert(e.data.msg)});
  msg ="hello";
  $("#test2").click({msg: msg}, function(e){alert(e.data.msg)});
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/h36pf/

Answer (score 1):

on document ready your javascript code is executed. at this point the click functions get bound to the two buttons and `msg` is set first to hi and then the next lines are executed and `msg` gets overwritten with hello.
at the time the click is triggered `msg` is already overwritten and thus outputs hello.

this is the right and expected behaviour though. you can overcome this issue by using either two variables or by setting them in the moment of the click (in the click function).

Comment: another option would be to scope the variable.

Comment: I wouldn't call it global, as it is not accessible from the window context. Yes, both functions refer to the same `var`, but it's scoped inside the DOM ready handler function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior.  It is often unintuitive, but is how javascript works.  The easiest way to get your intended result is to use a function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var msg ="hi";
  $("#test1").click(getCallback(msg));
  msg ="hello";
  $("#test2").click(getCallback(msg));
});

function getCallback(msg){
    return function(){
        alert(msg);
    }
}
```

The `msg` parameter within `getCallback` has a separate `msg` variable for each call which will maintain the correct value for each separate call.

Comment: @neal You are correct.  Realized that but got pulled away.  Just going to remove it as I don't have time to fix it atm.